# Translate: tool isn't working

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools

The translate: tool available to mods in chat seems to be broken. It refuses to translate things for me:

[image]

(this was in the [sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37237352#37237352))

This has been confirmed to not work very often for other mods in the TL as well. Can we please fix this, if it's not a problem on the Bing side?

Comment: You have been ninja'd by 2 seconds.